# Lost all my badges after re-login

Tags: support, badges, login

This morning SO asked me to re-login (I use google as the openid provider, associated to a google corporate account - not @gmail.com).

While doing so, I received an "We haven't seen this account before" message. So I was a little worried I did anything wrong.

After that, I was presented with my "regular" login page... except all my badges were lost!

Not that I had lots of them (I had like 9) but I liked them.

My rep points, questions, answers and votes show up correctly though.

Here's my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312586/egarcia) in case it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have resolved itself. I've got my badges back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I liked the idea of the system just giving you a "Lost" badge as a compensation. But giving you back your old badges is an acceptable solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

That account has 10 badges...

Comment: 10 is *like* 9!