# Some users are more enthusiastic than others

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, activity-badges

https://stackoverflow.com/users/89335?tab=activity#tab-top

This user has earned the Enthusiast badge (visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days) *twice*.

Comment: This appears to be related to merged accounts, as I saw badges awarded similarly [earlier today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46013/lost-all-my-badges-after-re-login) too.

Comment: @Gnome: Sounds likely enough, if both accounts had the enthusiast badge (which in turn doesn't sound likely).

Comment: Different accounts from work and home?  (I have no life, so yes, I check from both.. ><)  What I first saw is those badges (including many "beginner" bronzes) awarded so close together on a year old account, initially missed 2x Enthusiast.

Comment: Just as I was starting to feel that I'd done everything that I could for this community, you go and show me this.  I will redouble my efforts!

Comment: @Bill - *slacker.*

Comment: I'd love to have dual Enthusiast badge....

Comment: @Josh - Sorry, dual wielding is not available for your character class.

Comment: Would it be terribly uncool if I said I had no idea what a character class is?

Comment: @Josh it is from WoW and other class-based games. Think Warrior vs Hunter vs Priest. Warriors can dual-wield weapons (2 weapons instead of 1), priests can't.

Comment: @Chacha: it's from Dungeons and Dragons and other pen-and-paper RPGs long before WoW came around.  or did i just date myself?

Comment: If you're dating yourself this says something deeply sad about geekdom.  Me, I pay for my dates.

Comment: @ttmrichter: it's not deeply sad, it's *totally normal* ...  paying for your dates, now that's deeply sad.  ;)

Comment: quack quixote: Touché.

Comment: Huh, I was sure this had been discussed before, but I can't find a dupe... maybe it was just mentioned in a comment rather than a full-on post.

Comment: My push tomorrow will fix up all the invalid badges. (that is remove all single award badges that were awarded more than once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have isolated where this can happen, but a simple fix for now is to simply remove all badges that are single award and were awarded more than once. There are forty or so affected badges in the whole system.

If you are affected by this and are unhappy, sorry, we should be allowed to fix bugs.

Comment: Ping to remind you to set this to `[status-completed]`.

Comment: His account was merged?  Why is there nothing in his history?

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely a bug. When accounts are merged and a reputation recalc is done, a badge recalc should be done as well and ineligible/duplicate badges removed.  I don't see any good reason why badges should be permanent and irrevokable*.

*<sub>Except for programmer laziness, which is only excusable up to a point.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with two accounts being merged together.

Comment: I finally have a reason to make 42 sockpuppet accounts, and visit the site with each one of them every day...

Comment: Shouldn't one-time-only badges be rechecked in such cases, though?