# So what's the deal with these account merges?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, merge-accounts

Can I have two stackoverflow accounts, not upvoting each other, but basically I now have double the cap, and then later I merge them, etc? Rep wills be summed, multiply-awarded badges added up, etc?

How many of such accounts can you have? Wouldn't this break the cap system?

Comment: I bet that you're triggered by the case Oscar Reyes. He never used two accounts simultaneously. He just stopped at 10K, created new one, stopped at 10K again, created new one and about halfway he apparently finally decided to merge them anyway.

Comment: @BalusC: indeed Oscar's comment was what finally made me ask the question, but I've read about similar cases. Sorry don't remember name right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two accounts are merged, the rep of the combined account is recalculated at the same time. That would eliminate rep cap exploits.

I don't think badges are recalculated, though. I have seen a user with two Enthusiast badges, but I don't know whether it was intentional or an oversight (see [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/some-users-are-more-enthusiastic-than-others), which has not been given a status).