# New features (and New badges) as 9 July 2010

Tags: support, badges

I noticed there's some new badges as from today.

From the name of those badges, I inferred there is some new features to put a bounty on someone else question.

Is there any place where those changes are announced? (and the new badges listed?)

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/a-better-notification-of-significant-modifications-on-the-trilogy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Announcements of new features tend to happen in the [Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/), though if you don't follow it regularly (like me) you can miss them.

The other thing to do is check for questions that have been recently tagged [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) here on Meta. This often precedes the blog post.

Additionally if you hang out on Meta you might see questions being posed by Jeff and the other diamond mods that indicate that something is in the offing. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56066/what-do-we-do-with-badges-that-are-no-longer-applicable) for questions that revealed the bounty badges and the newly added information about which post was responsible for which badge.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the badges are new, but the change to the bounty system was announced on the [SO blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

I spotted several new badges: [Altruist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/222/altruist), [Benefactor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor) & [Promotor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/220/promoter)

Comment: There is an Investor too.

Answer (score 3):

ripper234 covers the bounty system change. The bounty badges have not yet been officially announced outside of the [original discussion for implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names) and some scattered [status-completed] tags.

In addition, it's easy to miss but there's also a new Copy Editor badge for 600 edits. It was [announced over in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/a-higher-level-strunk-white-badge-1000-edits-or-such).

Answer (score 0):

I'll blog this later, I wanted to make sure all the bugs and kinks are worked out before I do so.