# Reason No Longer Available Badge Description - Could be improved

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, badges

**Edit:**

This appears to actually be a bug.  Grace Note is seeing the deleted question title in the badge description, and I am not.  See Grace's answer for links and all of that fun stuff.

[One of my badges on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question?user_id=2598) has a 'Reason not available' for its title.  I know that it's because that question got deleted.

**My suggestion:**

In the case where a 'reason is not available' it should be fairly simple to find out if the question was deleted (soft deleted) or migrated (question is still there, but answers moved) and show that instead.

Instead of:

jun 29 at 21:42 **Reason is no longer available**

Do:

jun 29 at 21:42 **Question deleted** or **migrated**

Comment: `Reason is no longer available` should become the official Motto of Meta.

Comment: Okay, I'm missing out on a feature here.  Where do you see your badges' titles?  I thought perhaps you meant the mouseover text for badges on your profile, but those all work for me, even for questions I know were deleted.

Comment: @Popular Click on the badge itself, it leads to a new page. This was just added about 4 hours ago, no big announcement other than [status-completed] [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge).

Comment: To save everyone else the time, I went through the [timeline view](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5188/timeline) of the question, and there are +32/-1 votes *after* the post was migrated, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56066/what-do-we-do-with-badges-that-are-no-longer-applicable

Comment: @mmyers Thanks for removing that apostrophe.  I hate when people use the wrong 'its'.  I can't believe I did it.

Comment: I'll get this sorted, its actually a fairly complex fix, as I need a different message for questions and answers. So I need to add new badge reasons types ... long story, anyway Ill sort it next week.

Comment: @Waffles, thanks for the response.

Comment: @waffles Mighty long "week" you have there...

Answer (score 1):

Soft deleted posts still show up on the listing, at least as far as I've seen. For example, see [this deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11927/question-moved-from-stackoverflow-to-superuser-got-deleted) that yielded [this badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer?user_id=132959). At least, I'm assuming that's a deleted question, from the fact that I get the 404 page at <10k, and there's a badge attributed to that question.

**Update**

On some review, it seems there are a number of badges where there's "Reason is no longer available" when the reason is still alive and kicking. I noticed this on the Gaming Beta, more than half the people with Nice Answer badge on the Meta have that listed, but all of them have a valid post. I haven't checked the other Trilogy sites, but given jjnguy's report for his own Good Question badge, I'm inclined to believe there's something fishy in the storage.

Comment: Well, none of my posts should be hard deleted.  My one **Good Question** badge was for a post that was migrated to meta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296

Comment: It is shown as No Longer Available. http://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question?user_id=2598

Comment: @Justin Don't know what to say. It's two separate behaviors being given to the same scenario.

Comment: Hey, @waffles, what's going on?

Comment: @Grace, yeah I can see the question your badge is linked to.

Comment: @Justin Could you check [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15055/claudiu) for me? I think that might be a Great/Famous Question badge pair that matches your scenario, but I can't tell if there just is no record or if there's a deleted question or not.

Comment: @Grace, what do you want me to check?

Comment: @Justin I wanted to see if you could find a deleted stub for a Great and Famous Question by that user - there's 2 badges with the same "Reason No Longer Available" and I wanted to see if it matched your scenario. I don't know how easily you can see the deleted posts from a user, but I'm hoping it's something of an option.

Comment: The way I knew in my case was because I was very familiar with the question that got deleted.  I was able to search in google for the deleted question's title and find it that way.  Otherwise I dunno how you could find which question those badges were (or should be) tied to.

Comment: @Justin Hm, I see. Well, guess we're out of luck, then.