# Could we switch to wss:// for the live refresh?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, live-refresh, proxy

Currently, the live refresh feature uses an insecure websocket connection (`ws://`) to fetch updates.

However, this does not work with HTTP proxies due to the "HTTP connection upgrade" that happens in the websockets protocol. Websockets with TLS (`wss://`) work fine, though.

Given that a lot of SO users are behind corporate and university proxies, could websockets be upgraded to TLS?

Comment: Won't it require SSL on the servers? As far as I came to know from posts here, Stack Overflow is still missing this.

Comment: It would indeed require SSL on all servers, and as such valid certificates on all subsites. Given that browsers only accept certificates from valid and respected authorities, this costs money, an awful lot for all the sites involved (although a wildcard on `.stackexchange.com` would cover many). Offer to pay for it and I'm sure someone will consider it  ;)  I think however that, while HTTPS overhead on regular pages is negligible, it could be a relatively hefty strain on the WS servers, not sure which architecture is used for that part.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Just on `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com`. I don't think they will need HTTPS all over the network, though that would be nice as well. ALso, it could be opt in, reducing load to almost nothing.

Comment: @Niels: No, only on the websockets servers.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware that all sites connect to the same websocket server. Makes sense though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We are currently investigating our options to offer SSL in various capacities; this work (web-sockets) is included in that investigation.

Shhhh... don't tell anyone, but if you look carefully *right now* here on meta....

Comment: Any estimated timeline on this?

Comment: @Manishearth there's a default answer for that around these parts... "6 to 8 weeks". However, in truth: I'm not involved in that, so I can't give you a timescale.

Comment: Can we tag it with [`status-planned`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned)?

Comment: @hims056 oh, go on then

Comment: "6 to 8 weeks"... I swear I've seen request 2+ years old with such answer still pending. ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Give it 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @Oded you mean, like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56428/152859)? [Week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56428/reason-no-longer-available-badge-description-could-be-improved#comment133447_56428) spanning for nearly three years, think it's a world record! :D

Comment: `weeks` is the variable's name @ShaWizDowArd, and unfortunately (for us) it's a `long int`.

Comment: @Yannis at least it's not **unsigned** int! :)

Comment: Whoa. Magic!!!! :D :D

Comment: wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ congrats!