# WebSocket connection sometimes hangs while being behind a proxy

Tags: support, javascript, web-sockets

I am at work, and I am behind a Squid proxy. Usually everything works fine. But from time to time, I get this (in chrome console:)

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502

And that prevent every ajax request (When you click edit for example) from working. What could be wrong ?

Another problem is that approx 50% of pages that I load, I have to reload because the first time it hanged. This may be linked to the same issue. All of this is very irritating.

I don't have details about the proxy server, so that might be very hard to reproduce. But I am interested if you have any pointers.

Note: I have no problems whatsoever using a normal internet connexion.

Comment: `What could be wrong ?` - a buggy proxy, for instance.

Comment: The error you got means the **web sockets** connection failed, it got nothing to do with the AJAX failing to trigger, which happens when the CDN is blocked thus required JS files are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by someone up the chain between you and SE running [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) in [transparent mode](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy) and SE's heavy use of websockets.

Unfortunately the squid devs refuse to implement WS support for some reason. Oddly enough web sockets over https via squid work great.

Comment: Well, switching to secure web sockets [is planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177050/152859) so sounds like it will solve this problem.