# Link to CC license in "add image" popup covers "add picture" button on some sites (but not others)

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, hyperlinks, images

On math.SE, when I go to add a picture to a post, the link to the Creative Commons license overlaps the "add picture" button:

> [image]

Checking a few other sites:

TeX.SE:

> [image]

meta.SO:

> [image]

physics.SE:

> [image]

I'm not sure what makes some SE sites have this problem and others not, but a fix would be very much appreciated.

---

By the way, looking at all of these boxes, something greatly disturbs me:

*Why is the title of the box "Add* **Image***" but the button text "Add* **picture***"?*

Unless there's a reason for this inconsistency, I'd suggest choosing one term or the other.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ has the same issue.

Comment: Real and very annoying problem; affects [so] too.   But, I don't agree with the need for "foolish consistency" regarding "image" and "picture".  Using two different terms, in this case, can be useful in conveying what is being done.  Both terms are very overloaded in English, using them together removes some ambiguity.  "I tried to upload my virtual machine *image*, but that stupid site took forever and then said it was invalid!"

Comment: @Ben "planned" as in "it's currently in review and will be fixed shortly", or as in "6-8 weeks"? Sorry to nag but the second usually means.. never.. from long experience here. ([three years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56428/152859) are pretty much eternity in web terms)

Comment: @Sha, it will be fixed soon as in days, not weeks or years.

Comment: @Ben cheers, love the new generation of devs here! :-)

Comment: @Ben: It seems like this has been fixed, at least as far as I see. Would you like to post an answer announcing this, which I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jamiec said, this was a layout problem.  Fortunately I didn't have to fix it dozens of times :-)

I would say "it'll be in the next build", but it has been deployed for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a recent change to add that licensing text to the add image (picture?) dialog.

Stylesheets are maintained on a per-site basis, so unless the maintainer of the site-specific stylesheet has updated it, there appears to be a layout problem.

[Sklivvz](https://stackexchange.com/users/4623/sklivvz?tab=accounts) recently [flagged this up on skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/image-upload-text-is-broken)