# Lost badge count after visiting Site Tour

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I'm participating a **Private** Beta of Ukrainian Language.StackExchange.

At some moment, I've visited the Site Tour, and BOOM! — all my badges displayed in the header frame are lost. They still exist in the [corresponding section of profile](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster).

[image]

[image]

I haven't logged out or something. The problem appeared immediately after I navigated away from Site Tour to another page.

**To me, it looks like a bug. Is it?**

I've seen [similar posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46013/lost-all-my-badges-after-re-login) here at Meta, but they all complain about losing badges after logging out and in or [changing the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120058/lost-badges-tags-and-flag-weight-after-openid-problem?s=6|0.8571) how to login.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Viewing the tour page without the Informed badge does indeed cause your badge counts to be cleared out. The award function must be borked.

Comment: Actually seems unrelated to the tour page. Any badge being awarded can trigger this. And we can likely [blame Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/832590514063015936).

Comment: I poked Nick and he is digging into it.

Comment: @bluefeet http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5591691#5591691 !!! :O ;p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a query issue with a major update I did - I have fixed the query and re-synced badge counts (which happens nightly as well). The heads up on a bug was much appreciated.